# Top bar too small, chrome and firefox render mismatch

Tags: 18.04, unity, gnome, xorg, fonts

I consider myself a n00b in Linux and have recently moved to Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. I have integrated Intel graphics on my machine. My Ubuntu top-bar and its fonts are extremely small when compared to regular window titles and rest of the system fonts. I have install gnome-tweaks and have the fonts at size 11 which is normal, as well as have the scaling factor at 1.0, again normal. I have a feeling I may have messed up my graphics settings and have no idea how to fix it, any help or guidance is really appreciated. Please help. This is really annoying me as fonts are too big on Firefox and the power button on the top bar is too small to even look at for the normal eye.

A few relevant settings for context: Please do ask me or enlighten what else to look for to debug this issue better.

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Desktop)

$ xrandr --listproviders Providers: number : 1 Provider 0: id: 0x4a cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 7 associated providers: 0 name:Intel

$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 5120 x 1440, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP1 connected primary 2560x1440+2560+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 550mm x 310mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+
   2048x1080     60.00    24.00  
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP2 connected 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 550mm x 310mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+
   2048x1080     60.00    24.00  
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  

$ lshw | grep -A5 "Motherboard" 
description: 
  Motherboard product: 00CV7F
  vendor: Dell Inc.
  physical id: 0
  version: A00
  serial: /6KN6BT2/CNFCW008BS00KQ/
```

---

Note how different the rendering of the same page is between chrome and Firefox (bigger). Also watch out for how thin the top bar is as well as the font of the launchpad app names.

Chrome vs Firefox Rendering:

[image: chrome vs firefox]

Launchpad Fonts for Apps:

[image: launchpad]

Comment: Here you go. Note how different the rendering of the same page is between chrome and Firefox (bigger). Also watch out for how thin the top bar is as well as the font of the launchpad app names.
Chrome vs Firefox Rendering - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cw1OT.png
Launchpad Fonts for Apps - https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugPJL.jpg

Comment: Did you mess around with `about:config` in Firefox? What happens when you change `layout.css.dpi` to `-1`? What is the physical size/dpi of your displays?